# Can we change something so that the chapter is at the left side?

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

Using the following commands:

```
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]
```

the word "CHAPTER 2" for example is appeared at the right side of the page.

Can we change something so that it appears at the left side of the page?

Comment: If you want everything at the left, you don't need any `\filsomethin`: this is the default!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both elements (chapter name+number, and chapter title) flushed to the left margin, remove `\filletf` and `\filright` from your code:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule] 

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a command that both elements are on the left side? (I accidentally wrote in the right side but I meant left, I edited it)

Comment: @MaryStar Please see my updated answer.